# Android Wear Activity starts always white

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch

I have a dark watchface and i start my wear app through clicking on the watchface or if i receive a firebase cloud message.
I'm using regular old layout files (like ConstraintLayout).

At first my app was white but now i would like to switch to a black layout and now i realised that the app always slides in with a complete white layout.
I disabled the slide effect with adding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION to the intent, but it still shows a white layout while starting.

I tried to set everything i found to black, the background of the layout, background at theme and so on.
I noticed that the preview of my activity layout shows a little white ring:

[image]

It would be way nicer if i would not see the app starting completely white for a fraction of a second.

Currently working on a Samsung Galaxy Watch 5

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the theme you are using is the default... check in the manifest and in the themes.xml

Comment: yes i checked the theme. i even set a background color in the theme...

Comment: if you are using a custom theme add the following:
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>